# Whats wrong this live preview jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this script in jsfiddle, that while im typing it should show display the live text underneath.

its a simple script, but i cnt seem to see what the problem is, thanks :))

http://jsfiddle.net/XWsqz/

---

*EDIT: Adding code from link.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someTextBox').keyup(function(){
        $('#target').html(this.val());
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="someTextBox"></textarea>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: getaway - I took care of it here, but please place your code in the question in the future. Thanks. :o)

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the minor flaw in your event binding. See what happens when you hold down a letter? It will eventually update the target when you let the key go, but did you try pasting text with the mouse? You need to bind on more than just the keyup event if you want this to work for all updates to the textarea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()` because `this` points to the DOM element and not the jquery element which has the `.val()` function defined:

```
$('#target').html($(this).val());
```

Comment: can i add something addtional to the html, on top of the target id, for instance <b>about me</b>, this should only be visible when the user is typing

Answer (score 6):

As everyone is suggesting, `$(this).val()` will work. However, it doesn't make a lot of sense to incur the overhead of creating a jQuery wrapped object on every single keypress.  `this.value` is a better option if you don't need jQuery's extended methods on that element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#someTextBox').keyup(function(){
    $('#target').html(this.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you certain `this.value` is cross-browser safe for a `<textarea>`?

Comment: It is.  That's exactly what jQuery's val() eventually returns for textareas.

Comment: +1 Yes, you're right. I thought there was a `textarea` issue somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()`.

The former is a jQuery object, the latter, I think, is simply a DOM node.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#someTextBox').keyup(function(){
            $('#target').html($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XWsqz/8/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()`

Answer (score 0):

.val() is a jQuery function, so it only works when you're calling a jQuery object.

```
this
```

is not jQuery on its own (in your example). You have to wrap it in $( ), like so:

```
$(this)
```

So the correct way would be like so:

```
$("#target").html( $(this).val() );
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, this answer is valid. The downvote was likely a "strategic" move.